# Locked out of SSH terminal

Tags: oracle-cloud-infrastructure, ubuntu-22.04

I manated to lock myself out of SSH on an Canonical-Ubuntu-22.04 SSH always free server. do anyone know how i can get access back?

PS C:\Users\mikel> ssh -i ~/.ssh/ssh-key-2022-10-19.key ubuntu@129.xxx.200.16
ssh: connect to host 129.xxx.200.16 port 22: Connection refused

Comment: Connection refused usually means that the server isn’t allowing access to, or nothing is listening on, port 22. Rather than it being about your credentials?

Comment: You can try accessing it via the cloud console. You may need to paste your SSH private key into the `~/.ssh/id_rsa` file in the console.

Answer (score -1):

ssh: connect to host 129.xxx.200.16 port 22: Connection refused

means the remote host is sending the reject flags back, it can be due to

1. firewall blocking ssh port
2. iptables blocking port 22
3. security groups (Ingress, egress) blocking port 22

First check if you have allowed port 22 in console, if yes
then login to instance via console connection and then try to debug 1,2 points